# Why are literal HTML strings being appended to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When prepending or appending to an element, it literally puts the text and doesn't compile in HTML:

```
var banner ={
    'Format': '90x120cm',
    'Value': 35
};
// var premium = { key: values };

function defineProduct(data) {
        var item = $('span.tooltip')[0];
        console.log($('span.tooltip'));
        for(var keys in data){
            console.log(keys);
            item.append('<div class="item"><div class="left">'+keys+':</div><div class="right ">'+data[keys]+'</div></div>');
        }
    }

defineProduct(banner);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="three-columns">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="image-holder">
                <a href='' id="premium" class="tooltips">
                <img src="" class="premium-img" width="85px" height="79px">
                <p class="description">Cartão <br><span style="color: #ffc600;" class="different">premium</span></p>
                    <span class="tooltip"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        <!-- Same thing from above different description -->
        <!-- ditto -->
</div>
```

Output:
[image]

What have I tried/used:

- `.get();`
- `.prepend(string);`
- `.html(string);`
- `.text(string);` <– I don't know why, but I did
- `document.createTextNode(string);`
- set a variable which contains HTML tags strings and set to one of the previous attempts

And the reason I used `.get()` is because I have more than one object that are equivalent to the quantity of their elements, in this case, I have 3. So, for every append, I have different information. E.g.: .get(0), .get(1), etc

Comment: Use `.eq(0)` instead of `[0]` in `var item = ...;` as `eq` return a jQuery object and `[]` return the raw HTML DOM element. Or wrap the DOM element in a jQuery object: `var item = $( $('span.tooltip')[0] );`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using [`ParentNode.append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) to append a literal [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) which is appended as a text node instead of `jQuery#append` here:

```
var item = $('span.tooltip')[0];
```

The `[0]` access the underlying DOM element in the jQuery object. Remove the `[0]` to use jQuery methods (or [`eq(0)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) for the first element in the selection collection as a jQuery object) on it or use [`Node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
item.append....
```

you can use:

```
item.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',....
```

> [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML): parses the specified text as HTML or XML and inserts the resulting nodes into the DOM tree at a specified position.

```js
var banner = {
      'Format': '90x120cm',
      'Value': 35
  };

  function defineProduct(data) {
      var item = $('span.tooltip')[0];
      //console.log($('span.tooltip'));
      for (var keys in data) {
          //console.log(keys);
          item.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="item"><div class="left">' + keys + ':</div><div class="right ">' + data[keys] + '</div></div>');
      }
  }

  defineProduct(banner);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="three-columns">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="image-holder">
            <a href='' id="premium" class="tooltips">
                <img src="" class="premium-img" width="85px" height="79px">

                <p class="description">Cartão <br><span style="color: #ffc600;" class="different">premium</span></p>
                <span class="tooltip"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- Same thing from above different description -->
        <!-- ditto -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use of insertAdjacentHTML will let you open for XSS attacks!!!

Comment: @ShivamKumar Yes, you are right. Indeed the XSS can happen also with jQuery append. My intention was to prove you can use pure javascript avoiding jQuery.

Comment: XSS means **Cross**-Site-Scripting. Anything you do Client Side _can_ become an XSS attack, BUT only when data is send to a Server. _Kitchen knives can kill people_**!!!**

Answer (score 0):

**[0]** needs to be removed from **$('span.tooltip')[0]** . It is trying to access first child of **".tooltip"** span which is not available in DOM.